# Why does "npm install" prefix my packages with "node_modules" in my "package-lock.json" file?

Tags: npm, prefix, package-lock.json

I've never had this happen before, but now, when I `npm install` in the root directory of my app, my `package-lock.json` updates all the packages with `node_modules/`. What is causing this?

Here's what I get before running `npm i`

[image: before running command]

Here's what I get after running `npm i`

[image: after running command]

Comment: Did something change recently in `package.json` with `ajv` and `amqp-connection-manager`?

Comment: @MilanTenk this happens with ALL my packages - not just these two. It happens when I `npm install` or `npm uninstall` (anything that updates package-lock.json) locally on my machine. When I do so on my company's ec2 instances, it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What version of `npm` (and `node`) are you using?

`npm` v7 has been released, and it ships with `node` v15. That introduces some big changes due to the new support for *workspaces*... which introduces `package-lock.json` v2.

I'm going to go out on a limb: I suspect you're running `npm` v7 locally and your EC2 instances are not.

https://github.blog/2020-10-13-presenting-v7-0-0-of-the-npm-cli/

Comment: Thank you Nicholas, that was precisely the problem. I was running the newest version of node. I downgraded with `nvm use v15.6.0` and `npm i` no longer prefixes my packages with `node_modules/`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce issue from OP's question on my computer by running

```
npm install -g npm@7
```

and then running

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Inspecting *my-app/package-lock.json* confirmed changed behaviour.

I then downgraded *npm* to 6.14.11 using

```
npm install -g npm
```

Deleted folder *my-app* and repeated `create-react-app` step above. This time, inspecting *my-app/package-lock.json* confirmed "normal" behaviour.